# Python 3.2 Passive User Input

Tags: python, input

Is there a way to program a function that takes user input without requesting it? For example, during a game of tic-tac-toe, the user could press "Q" at any time and the program would close?

Comment: How is the game being displayed? Tkinter? Just printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, and they are all different.

If your game is a terminal application using `curses`, you would catch the `q` when you call `getch()`, and then raise `SystemExit` or simply break out of your `while` loop that many `curses` applications use.

Using `tkinter` or another GUI library, you would bind a key press event to your `Frame` widget that holds the tic-tac-toe board.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just printing the board out (I have a basic Tic-Tac-Toe game that does that), during input you could close it (even though you specifically asked otherwise):

user_option = input("Enter a space to move to, or 'Q' to quit: ")

```
try:
    if user_option.lower() == 'q': # makes everything lowercase so it is easier to handle
        import sys
        sys.exit("Game Terminated.")
except TypeError:
    # other code
```

I'm not sure how the player chooses to move, so I used `try` and `except`. In my Tic-Tac-Toe game, I have the user input an integer, which corresponds to a space on the board.

Or, you can just have the user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which is the automatic `KeyBoardInterrupt` in Python (ends the program).